# jquery fire event on keydown in an input occuring in last tr of table body when rows are continually being appended

Tags: jquery

I have this table:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <th>LastName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="firstname" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="lastname" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is the add rows to the table. I want to do this whenever a keydown event occurs when the cursor is in an input occurring in the bottom row of the table.

So I made some javascript:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:last td input').keydown(function (e) {

  $('#myTable tbody tr:last').clone().appendTo('#myTable');



        });
```

This works to a point in that it adds rows. The problem is the keydown event stays tied to the top row of the table. This is not want instead I want the event tied to the newly appended row which will be the bottom row of the table.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? How to fix?

**EDIT:**

What I should have mentioned sorry is that I would like it to work for only the newly added row and none of the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$(document).on('keydown','#myTable tbody tr:last td input',function (e) {

    $('#myTable tbody tr:last').clone().appendTo('#myTable');

  });
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qaAgz/)

Comment: Thanks, this works. However still unsure why mine didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate on closest static element for dynamically added elements like this

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('keydown','tr:last td input',function (e) {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R7BUq/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `live()`(will be deprecated) or `on()` jquery function for the new created DOM.

your script should be like this:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:last td input').on('keydown',function (e) {

  $('#myTable tbody tr:last').clone().appendTo('#myTable');

 });
```

or

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:last td input').live('keydown', function (e) {

  $('#myTable tbody tr:last').clone().appendTo('#myTable');

  });
```

Comment: live is no more in latest version of Jquery it has been removed.